# Where to put WHERE in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I cannot find where I can put my WHERE clause in my query. It seems like I tried every possible position but nothing is working.

```
SELECT res
FROM (
SELECT `date`,SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE) AS res
FROM royalties 
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 12
) a
ORDER BY `date` ASC
WHERE `BUNDLE_ARTIST` = '" . $artist_name . "'
```

Comment: @AlephDvorak It's in his title and tags

Comment: As an aside note, judging by the `'" . $artist_name ."'` construction I assume you are doing this in PHP. I hope you are escaping the variable value properly, otherwise I might be tempted to run a search for my favorite artist called `"; DELETE FROM royalties; SELECT "` :-)

Check out [mysql-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) in that case.

Comment: In addition to what @CompuChip said, I'd recommend looking into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), specifically the part near the end about protection against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd have thought you need to put it after the `FROM` clause in the subquery:

```
SELECT res
FROM (
SELECT `date`,SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE) AS res
FROM royalties 
WHERE `BUNDLE_ARTIST` = '" . $artist_name . "'
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 12
) a
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

You can see this order documented in [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using an inner query in your clause. You made some mistakes. Try this:

```
SELECT res
FROM 
(
    SELECT `date`,SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE) AS res
    FROM royalties 
    WHERE `BUNDLE_ARTIST` = '" . $artist_name . "'
    GROUP BY `date`
    ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 12
) inner query
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

Answer (score -4):

Usually, I find including your WHERE clause before the ORDER and GROUP clauses is best:

```
SELECT res
FROM (
SELECT `date`,SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE) AS res
FROM royalties 
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 12
)
WHERE `BUNDLE_ARTIST` = '" . $artist_name . "'
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

Comment: That won't work, the subquery doesn't return a BUNDLE_ARTIST column.